# How to show different listviews from pressing the item of a diffrent listview in the same screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview

Suppose, I have a list List1 = [A,E,M,X] which I can show using listview.builder horizontally. I have some other lists such as List2 = [a,b,c,d], List3 = [e,f,g,h] etc which I can show under the listview of List1 on a similar way.
What I want is whenever a user presses A from List1, the below listview will automatically show the list List2 = [a,b,c,d].  When a user presses B from List1, the below list will automatically show the list List3 = [e,f,g,h]. I used GestureDetector to detect the press in List1 which works fine. And, all these has to happen in one screen.

Here is my home screen where I'm calling those 2 listviews,

```
Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
        children: <Widget>[
          HomeTopInfo(),
          FoodCategory(),
          SubFoodCategory(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
```

This is the first list

```
class FoodCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodCategoryState createState() => _FoodCategoryState();
}

class _FoodCategoryState extends State<FoodCategory> {
  final List<Category> _catagories = categories;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _onSelected(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: _catagories.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _onSelected(index);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    _catagories[index].title,
                    style: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index
                        ? TextStyle(
                            color: kTextColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )
                        : TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                  if (_selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == index)
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                      height: 3,
                      width: 22,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the second list which I'm showing under the first list

```
class SubFoodCategory extends StatelessWidget {
  final String category;
  SubFoodCategory({Key key, this.category}) : super(key: key);
  final List<SubCategory> _subCategories = subCategories;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(category);
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: _subCategories.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return FoodCard(
            subCategoryName: _subCategories[index].subCategoryName,
            imagePath: _subCategories[index].imagePath,
            numberOfItems: _subCategories[index].numberOfItems,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have seperate model class for both the list and used dummy data to populate all this. Which I'm doing right now is showing to list diffrently.
What I want is whenever I press a list item from the first list, I want to show a similar type of list under the first list.

Comment: Can you include a code you have tried so far or do you want us to make it for you?

Comment: I thought it would be a simple something which I couldnt figure out by my own. May be there is a little trick or may be even a widget which I'm not familiar with, thats why I didnt upload my code. Anyways, if you want I can upload the code.

Comment: You are required to add code with your question.. I have answered your question and if you want more help you will have to update your question with a reproducible code..

Comment: I added codes of my work.

Comment: Thr problem I'm having is I can show two different list right now, ome is food_category and another is sub_food_category below it. But I want this to be dynamic. Means, when I'll chose a category from food_category, I want to show a list from sub_food_categroy below it. When I'll press another listitem from food_category, it will show a different list but in a sub_food_delivery widget style.